# Exposing request method in generated Service Reference

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

In a generated Service Reference (imported from a WSDL), I have the following methods in the Client class, in the Reference.cs:

```
    public Namespace.Service.SalesOrderDetail newService(Namespace.Service.Contact orderContact, Namespace.Service.Contact installationContact, string customerReference, Namespace.Service.ServiceDetails[] serviceDetailsList) {
        Namespace.Service.newServiceRequest inValue = new Namespace.Service.newServiceRequest();
        inValue.orderContact = orderContact;
        inValue.installationContact = installationContact;
        inValue.customerReference = customerReference;
        inValue.serviceDetailsList = serviceDetailsList;
        Namespace.Service.newServiceResponse retVal = ((Namespace.Service.ServiceRequestPortType)(this)).newService(inValue);
        return retVal.salesOrder;
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Namespace.Service.newServiceResponse> Namespace.Service.ServiceRequestPortType.newServiceAsync(Namespace.Service.newServiceRequest request) {
        return base.Channel.newServiceAsync(request);
    }

    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Namespace.Service.newServiceResponse> newServiceAsync(Namespace.Service.Contact orderContact, Namespace.Service.Contact installationContact, string customerReference, Namespace.Service.ServiceDetails[] serviceDetailsList) {
        Namespace.Service.newServiceRequest inValue = new Namespace.Service.newServiceRequest();
        inValue.orderContact = orderContact;
        inValue.installationContact = installationContact;
        inValue.customerReference = customerReference;
        inValue.serviceDetailsList = serviceDetailsList;
        return ((Namespace.Service.ServiceRequestPortType)(this)).newServiceAsync(inValue);
    }
```

I've seen Python code that uses the same WSDL, and it is able to access the method as `response = client.newService(request)`.

I'd also like to access the method in that fashion, albeit `var task = client.newService(request); Task.WaitAll(task); var response = task.Result;`, but I can't seem to find the right combo of creating the service reference, without being forced to have expanded input parameters to the service.

Is there a magic combo for Service Reference creation that will allow me to just pass the request as a single object?

I'm not fussed on keeping the async functionality.

Comment: really hard to understand what you mean. are you wanting to disable async functionality?

Comment: No. I want to be able to access the API so I can call `client.newService(request)`, instead of `client.newService(orderContact, installationContact, customerReference, serviceDetailsList)`, but I'm not sure if I've used the wrong options when generating the service reference, or if I'm calling the service the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client of a service implements the interface that represents the service. It just so happens, and is shown in this example, that it doesn't necessarily make all those implemented method public.

So, to get around this, if I cast the client object to the service interface, I get to call the service as intended, regardless of what the client has made public.

```
var client = new ServiceClient();

var service = (Service)client;

var request = new newServiceRequest() { ... };

var response = service.newService(request);

client.Close();
```